# Can I overload operators where the operands are functions?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to have overloaded operators in F# where the operands are functions?

For example (using Chessie):

```
module AsyncTrialOperators =
  type Ops=
    /// Left-to-right Kleisli composition
    static member (>=>) (f:'a -> AsyncResult<'b,_>, g:'b -> AsyncResult<'c,_>) =
      fun x ->
        asyncTrial {
        let! y = f x
        let! z = g y
        return z }

    /// Left-to-right Kleisli composition
    static member (>=>) (f:'a -> AsyncResult<'b,_>, g:'b -> Result<'c,_>) =
      fun x ->
        asyncTrial {
        let! y = f x
        let! z = g y
        return z }

  // Example usage (doesn't compile)
  let f x = ok x
  let g x = fail x

  let z = f >=> g
```

Gives the following error:
`FS0043   Expecting a type supporting the operator '>=>' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `Ops` is not part of the arguments.

You can use the trick of moving one of the arguments to a lambda and then use the vacant argument to receive a dummy argument of the container type:

```
#r @"c:\packages\chessie.0.6.0\lib\net40\Chessie.dll"

open Chessie
open Chessie.ErrorHandling

type Ops=

    /// Left-to-right Kleisli composition
    static member (>=>) (_:Ops, g:'b -> Result<'c,_>) =
        fun (f:'a -> AsyncResult<'b,_>) x ->
            asyncTrial {
            let! y = f x
            let! z = g y
            return z }

/// Left-to-right Kleisli composition
    static member (>=>) (_:Ops, g:'b -> AsyncResult<'c,_>) =
        fun (f:'a -> AsyncResult<'b,_>) x ->
            asyncTrial {
            let! y = f x
            let! z = g y
            return z }
```

Then you can redefine `>=>` at global level:

```
let inline (>=>) x y = (Unchecked.defaultof<Ops> >=> y) x
```

But now you will realize that are passing the wrong arguments, f has to be of type `AsyncResult<_,_>`, since I'm not familiar with chessie I will use a Dummy function:

```
 let f x = Unchecked.defaultof<AsyncResult<int,int>>
 let g x = fail x
```

Now one more detail, to avoid the value restriction you'll have to add `x` on both sides:

```
let z x = (f >=> g) x
```

This will work, but I strongly advise you against this design.

If you ask me, overloading, specially at global level, has to follow some rules to be consistent. This kind of Ad-hoc overloading design a-la C# won't work well as you add more stuff, soon you'll get into situations where type inference doesn't know what do you want to do, or even the reader of your code.

If you want to use a generic (and well behaved) `>=>` have a look at the one defined in [F#+](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus)

Comment: Don't think I'll go down this route as it seems a bit klunky but certainly an interesting trick!